# Qt Creator - setting up a kit with a cross-compiler

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5, cross-compiling

I'm attempting to use Qt creator to cross-compile a project, but have an issue matching the Qt version and my specified compiler toolchain.

I have created a Kit setting up a Device, selecting my toolchain as the compiler (GCC ARM Linux in this case), but I only have a locally installed system Qt (5.0.2 on Mint x86).

Qt Creator understandably tells me the compiler cannot produce code for the Qt version; all the guides I have found suggest using a Qt compiled for the target platform. This doesn't make sense though - it attempts to run qmake compiled for a different architecture and fails

How do I install or configure/compile a Qt version to work with the cross compiler? Maybe I can modify my existing one to understand this setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This makes absolutely sense. The advice to use a Qt, which is compiled for your target platform is correct. But this does not mean that you use a Qt that was compiled natively **on** that target platform. You need to use a Qt, which was compiled with a special cross compiler on your host platform **for** your target platform. This way qmake and other build tools remain executable on your host, but create configurations for your target.

So, if you have a compiler, which can create ARM code, use it to build your Qt. Then you can create a kit in QtCreator out of this compiler/Qt pair.

Answer (score 0):

Greenflow is right. I would like to add some information. I have cross compiled Qt 5.4.1 on Windows having an ARM Linux as target platform. You just need to configure the build properly. Here's what I did:

```
./configure -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ .....
```

So Qt tools (qmake,moc,etc...) were built as Windows binaries and all the libraries were built as Linux binaries. Check for the available platforms in qtbase/mkspecs.